# How to place a navigation controoler upon a tabBar controller in iPhone without using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Can you provide me some good link or example, on how to place a navigation controller upon a tabBar controller in iPhone without using Interface builder.
i know to create tabBar controller . Plese tel me how to place a navigation in the view provided by tabBar controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, all you should have to do is create an `NSArray` with one or more `UINavigationController` instances and assign it to the `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers` property.

You'd have to adjust it, but something like this might work:

```
NSMutableArray* controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    UIViewController* innerController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    UINavigationController* outerController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:innerController] autorelease];
    [controllers addObject:outerController];
}

[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```